# Django query categories, exclude those without posts

Tags: django

I have these two models, post and categories.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    """ Categories """

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 80, help_text="Enter a descriptive and unique category name.")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 250, help_text="The slug is used to link category pages.")

class Post(models.Model):
    """ Blog posts """

    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name = 'blog_posts', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = models.TextField(help_text = "Type your blog post using plain text or mark-down format.")
```

I am trying to query all the categories that have posts, excluding categories which don't have yet posts. The SQL equivalent of:

```
SELECT * FROM category WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(category_id) FROM post)
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use annotation to count the posts and then filter based on the result:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Category.objects.annotate(posts_count=Count("blog_posts")).filter(post_count__gt=0)
```

Comment: OH and one more question pllease, how could I order the results using the amount of posts ascending? So the categories with more posts appear first? Thanks!

Comment: You can use the annotation results in `order_by()` just like filter.

Comment: Thanks! I am having a hard time. How would I edit this query to achieve that? categories = Category.objects.annotate(post_count=Count("blog_posts")).filter(post_count__gt=0).order_by('name')

Comment: `Category.objects.annotate(post_count=Count("blog_posts")).filter(post_count__gt=0).order_by('post_count')`